# How to convert token JWT to object in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, token

I have a ReactJS project that when I log in I save my token to local storage. How can I convert the token JWT to ab object and get id-user?

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NCwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJhdXRob3JpemF0aW9uIjoib3duZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTQ5NDkxMjksImV4cCI6MTY1NDk1MjcyOX0.5e-KzJ0Rv3iWmY5MFtEGjRXZBJNlddiZ97X8pHJD03g
```

[image: decoded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use basic JavaScript to decode it:

```js
const object = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering such obvious duplicates and mark as duplicate instead

Comment: Besides, `atob` uses standard base64 whereas JWT uses base64url. So this may even throw an exception ...

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61byQ.png)

Comment: Please post code and not pictures of code. Furthermore, if your code refers to an external library, you should at least mention which ...